# Approximating Lipschitz functions by non-zero ones

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-numbers, lipschitz-functions

Let $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb C$ be a Lipschitz function. Then $f^\prime \in L_\infty[0,1]$. For a given $\varepsilon > 0$, we may approximate $f^\prime$ in the supremum norm by a simple function $h$ within $\varepsilon$.

It seems that often I can manipulate the values of $h$ (if I start with some specific situations) so that the condition $\|f^\prime - h\|_\infty < \varepsilon$ is satisfied. Is there a way concluding that one can amend $h$ further so that:

- $\|f^\prime - h\|_\infty < \varepsilon$
- $\|f - h(0) - \int_0^\cdot h \|_\infty < 2 \varepsilon $,
- $\inf_{x\in [0,1]}|h(0) + \int_0^x h| > 0$?

Please note that there is room for changing $h$, so if initially we had $0\in h^{-1}(\{0\})$, nothing stops us from changing slightly the value on that preimage, etc.

I am seeking an argument that avoids invoking the initial form of $h$ explicitly (such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333365/approximating-bounded-measurable-functions-by-simple-functions-from-above)).

Comment: Exactly how do you prove what you claim? Seems clear to me that without further assumptions it does not follow that $\int_0 h$ is bounded away from zero.

Comment: Isn't it a mistake? Shouldn't be $f(0)+\int_0^\cdot h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would like to point out that those conditions imply that $|f'(0)-h(0)|<\varepsilon$ and $|f(0)-h(0)|<2\varepsilon$, which gives $|f'(0)-f(0)|<3\varepsilon$. Therefore I assume there's a small mistake in the formulation of the problem.

Now I assume that it's clear that it's possible to find a simple function $h$ such that

- $\|f^\prime  - h\|_\infty < \varepsilon$
- $\|f - f(0) - \int_0^\cdot h \|_\infty < \varepsilon$

Put $g_a(x):=a + \int_0^x h(t)dt $. It's a Lipschitz function, so the image $g_a([0,1])$ is compact. Therefore the condition $\inf_{x\in [0,1]}|g_a(x)| > 0$ is equivallent to $0\notin g_a([0,1])$.

We need a version of Sard's Theorem for Lipschitz functions. I think [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780404/image-of-lipschitz-map-measure-zero) is the proper version.

The function $g_{f(0)}$ has image of measure zero, therefore there exists $v\in B(0,\varepsilon)$ such that $v\notin g_{f(0)}([0,1])$, so $0\notin g_{f(0)-v}([0,1])$. Now observe that
$$\|f-f_{f(0)-v}\|_\infty = \left\|f-f(0)+v-\int_0^\cdot h\right\|_\infty \leq \left\|f-f(0)-\int_0^\cdot h\right\|_\infty+|v|<\varepsilon+\varepsilon. $$
Therefore for $a:=f(0)-v$ we have

- $\|f'-h\|_\infty<\varepsilon$,
- $\|f-a-\int_0^\cdot h\|_\infty<2\varepsilon$,
- $\inf_{x\in[0,1]}\left|a+\int_0^x h\right|>0$.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder where do you employ complex scalars? In the real case, you cannot approximate for example $f(x) = x - 1/2$ with non-zero functions.

Comment: This is in Sard's theorem. We have a function from the space $[0,1]$ with dimension 1 to the space  $\Bbb C$ with dimension 2.